# Sharing SurfaceView from a Service to Activity

Tags: android, camera, android-service, surfaceview, surface

I have a Service running in the background which is started by an activity. The service itself is a background Camera recorder. The Service tries to Starts Camera2 and writes to a Surface provided by the Media Recorder.

When I get the Activity runnning, now I want to have the live stream along with the  background recording. So far, I have been creating a SurfaceView in an Activity and passing it as a target to Camera2 when the surface is created from the Activity. But, I have to reinitialize the Camera2 API each time the Surface gets destroyed(ie Activity goes to the background). Is this the right approach to solve this problem? Is it possible for the Service to own the SurfaceView and pass a reference to Surface back to the Activity so that it can display the live feed without re initializing the Camera device?

Comment: You can make a surface in a service and add it using the window manager so it stays alive and renders over everything.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly; the SurfaceView has to live in the app process because it's closely tied to the app's UI state (and as you've noticed, it gets torn down every time the app goes in the background).  So it can't live in the service.

However, you could have the Service receive camera frames, and resend them to the app when it's in the foreground.  For example, you could use an ImageReader to read YUV frames from the camera, and then write those (with an ImageWriter) to a Surface the app provides from its own ImageReader (or SurfaceView if you can do the YV12 bit described below).  Then the camera doesn't need to be reconfigured when the app appears or disappears; the service can just start dumping the images to nowhere.

That does require the app to draw its own YUV frames, which is annoying, since there's unfortunately no requirement that a TextureView or SurfaceView will accept YUV_420_888 buffers.  If your camera device supports YV12 output, then that can be written directly to a SurfaceView or TextureView; otherwise, you'll probably need to implement some custom translation.  Most efficiently that can be done in JNI code, where you can use the NDK ANativeWindow APIs to lock the Surface from a SurfaceView, set its format to YV12, and write the YUV_420_888 image data into it (translating pixel stride/row stride as needed).

Comment: Or, you can write an OpenGL shader that will take whatever flavour of YUV_420_888 and display the resulting texture.

Comment: I like this approach ('Another level of indirection'). I will try this. Meanwhile, keeping the question open for other potential solutions.